# My test dataset accuracy score is 1.0 for Random Forest - is the issue to do with my code or my dataset?

Tags: classification, accuracy

I use these classification algorithms to test whether a URL is phishing or legitimate.

I have tried feature_importance, cross-validation, and hyperparameter tuning to the best of my ability, but I still get an accuracy score of 1.0. Now I am not sure if the problem is to do with my code or my dataset.

I created a dataset that includes 45 attributes and 1223 entries. Below is a screenshot of some of the data:
[image]

the status attribute is what deems the URL as phishing (1) or legitimate (0)

this is my code for the Random Forest classifier:

```
df = newData
features = ['length_url', 'length_hostname', 'ip', 'nb_dots', 'nb_hyphens',
       'nb_at', 'nb_qm', 'nb_and', 'nb_eq', 'nb_underscore', 'nb_slash', 
       'nb_colon', 'nb_semicolumn', 'https_token', 'ratio_digits_url',
       'ratio_digits_host', 'nb_subdomains', 'prefix_suffix', 
       'length_words_raw', 'char_repeat', 'shortest_words_raw',
       'shortest_word_host', 'shortest_word_path', 'longest_words_raw',
       'longest_word_host', 'longest_word_path', 'avg_words_raw',
       'avg_word_host', 'avg_word_path', 'nb_hyperlinks', 'ratio_intHyperlinks',
       'ratio_extHyperlinks', 'nb_extCSS', 'login_form', 'links_in_tags',
       'ratio_intMedia', 'ratio_extMedia', 'iframe', 'popup_window',
       'safe_anchor', 'onmouseover', 'empty_title',
       'domain_in_title']
X = df[features] 
y = df.status
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=10, n_estimators=50,random_state=0)
rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=rf.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

the array *features* consists of all the attributes of the dataset, excluding *url* and *status*. the accuracy score was 1.0

I have tried *feature_importance_* using the following code:

```
feature_imp = pd.Series(rf.feature_importances_, index=['length_url', 'length_hostname', 'ip', 'nb_dots', 'nb_hyphens',
                                                    'nb_at', 'nb_qm', 'nb_and', 'nb_eq', 'nb_underscore', 'nb_slash', 
                                                    'nb_colon', 'nb_semicolumn', 'https_token', 'ratio_digits_url',
                                                    'ratio_digits_host', 'nb_subdomains', 'prefix_suffix', 
                                                    'length_words_raw', 'char_repeat', 'shortest_words_raw',
                                                    'shortest_word_host', 'shortest_word_path', 'longest_words_raw',
                                                    'longest_word_host', 'longest_word_path', 'avg_words_raw',
                                                    'avg_word_host', 'avg_word_path', 'nb_hyperlinks', 'ratio_intHyperlinks',
                                                    'ratio_extHyperlinks', 'nb_extCSS', 'login_form', 'links_in_tags',
                                                    'ratio_intMedia', 'ratio_extMedia', 'iframe', 'popup_window',
                                                    'safe_anchor', 'onmouseover', 'empty_title',
                                                    'domain_in_title']).sort_values(ascending=False) 
sns.barplot(x=feature_imp, y=feature_imp.index)
plt.xlabel('Feature Importance Score')
plt.ylabel('Features')
plt.title("Visualizing Important Features", pad=15, size=30)
plt.savefig('barplot.png')
```

the output:
[image]

I also did cross-fold validation:

```
cv1 = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
model = RandomForestClassifier()
scores1 = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv1, n_jobs=-1)
print('Accuracy (k-fold cross validation): %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores1), std(scores1)))
cv2 = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
scores2 = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv2, n_jobs=-1)
print('Accuracy (repeated k-fold cross validation): %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores2), std(scores2)))
```

the output:
[image]